# I am trying to extract info from a remote page and parse it to html. What I have is not working

Tags: php, dom

I want to get all the information (date, location, price, etc.) from a remote page and parse it to HTML. I tried this script below but nothing appears to be happening:

```
<?php
$path = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Fukuoka-Prefecture--Japan?checkin=10%2F26%2F2015&checkout=11%2F03%2F2015&guests=&ss_id=xyn63dgs&page=1';
$html = file_get_contents($path);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'col-sm-12 row-space-2 col-md-6') {
        echo $tag->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error returned from the `file_get_contents()` it's giving you an error:

> **HTTP request failed!** HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in yada/yada/yada.php

Try using a `cURL` library (or script) that will emulate a browser, similar to below *(this is what I use when `file_get_contents()` fails. If it fails, remember that cURL is basically stateless, so if the destination site uses something based on sessions or cookies, you might be S.O.L.)*:

```
<?php

class   cURL
    {
        public      $response;
        protected   $sendHeader;

        protected   $PostFields;

        private     $query;

        public  function    __construct($query = '')
            {
                $this->sendHeader   =   false;
                $this->query        =   $query;
                if(!empty($this->query)) {
                        if(!is_array($this->query))
                            $this->response =   $this->Connect($this->query);
                        else
                            $this->encode();
                    }
            }

        public  function SendPost($array = array())
            {
                $this->PostFields['payload']    =   $array;
                $this->PostFields['query']      =   http_build_query($array);
                return $this;
            }

        public  function Connect($_url,$deJSON = true)
            {
                // Remote Connect
                $ch         = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                if(strpos($_url,"https://") !== false) {
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,2);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
                    }

                if(!empty($this->PostFields['payload'])) {
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($this->PostFields['payload']));
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->PostFields['query']);
                    }

                if(!empty($this->sendHeader))
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56');

                $decode     =   curl_exec($ch);
                $_response  =   ($deJSON)? json_decode($decode, true) : $decode;
                $error      =   curl_error($ch);

                curl_close($ch);
                return (empty($error))? $_response: $error;
            }

        public  function emulateBrowser()
            {
                $this->sendHeader   =   true;
                return $this;
            }

        public  function encode($_filter = 0)
            {
                foreach($this->query as $key => $value) {
                        $string[]   =   urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
                    }

                if($_filter == true)
                    $string =   array_filter($string);

                return implode("&",$string);
            }
    }
```

**To use:**

```
$path   =   'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Fukuoka-Prefecture--Japan?checkin=10%2F26%2F2015&checkout=11%2F03%2F2015&guests=&ss_id=xyn63dgs&page=1';
$cURL   =   new cURL();
$html   =   $cURL->emulateBrowser()->connect($path,false);
$dom    =   new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'col-sm-12 row-space-2 col-md-6') {
        echo $tag->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no output.. only blank

Comment: did you include both the class and the code on one page? I ran this exact code and it runs fine, no errors.

Comment: No, I thought I forgot something, but I didn't. At the top of your page, write: `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` See if you get errors

Comment: i dont know. but still no output here.. maybe i think my compiler broke

Comment: So you don't get any errors either after putting `ini_set("display_errors",1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your page?

Comment: Are you doing localhost or is there a link you can show me?

Comment: Yeah, that is localhost, that means it's not in a public domain to be reviewed. I can't see it.

Comment: Yup, that is all correct! For me it runs just fine. Do you have error logs that you can look at? You should since it's a localhost

Comment: i use phpstorm 9 .0 and xampp

Comment: I have xampp on my computer. I will try and test it to see if it works.

Comment: Under the "Manage Servers" tab, select the "Apache Web Server" then click the "Configure" button. Logs are available through there.

Comment: $path   =   'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Fukuoka-Prefecture--Japan?checkin=10%2F26%2F2015&checkout=11%2F03%2F2015&guests=&ss_id=xyn63dgs&page=1';
$cURL   =   new cURL();
$html   =   $cURL->emulateBrowser()->connect($path,false);
$dom    =   new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'col-sm-12 row-space-2 col-md-6') {
        echo $tag->nodeValue;
    }
}


Hi, @rasclatt.. i want to exact to all the attribute and it's value from this class. can you show me some solution.. thanks